Чем открыть файл формата сгенерированным init_seg_name в ffmpeg
-dash_segment_type webm
-init_seg_name "init-$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
-media_seg_name "sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"

В ffmpeg применяю данные настройки, использую кодек libvpx-vp9. На выходе получаю файлы
init-6.webm
sg-0-00001.webm

Первый вопрос что возникает, а в верное ли расширение задает webm? Один из файлов должен содержать временные метки и ссылку на видеофайл. Второй это видеоотрезок. Собственно верны ли расширения к данным файлам?
Как мне прочитать тот файл, которые содержит временные метки? Редактор Visual Studio Code, ни один из двух не открывает...

Зачем вам его читать? Это задача видеоплеера

Ну и да, тот файл, который «должен содержать временные метки», обычно имеет расширение mpd и к параметрам init_seg_name и media_seg_name не имеет никакого отношения

А с расширениями к файлам, тут верно? У других посмотрел, у каждого чуть ли не свое расширение у подобных файлов...
